# List of item damage checkboxes with severity input

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, web-app, layout, checkboxes

I have this web-app that is being used for intake and conditioning items. One of the pages currently has a list of 30+ damage type checkboxes that you check if the item has that damage.

This is what it currently looks like (but imagine 30+ checkboxes):

## [image]

Now whats needed is the ability to check the damage type and then select the severity of the damage (Slight or Moderate). So if I checked "Scuffs" I also need to select "Slight" or "Moderate" to say "Slightly Scuffed" or "Moderately Scuffed"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of check-boxes, you could have sliders that go from "not at all" to "very".

It might take a bit of a re-word on the categories though.

[image]

This equates to putting a value to how scuffed or gross something is. As you can see in the mock-up, I've added some dots to indicate the options in each one, in case you'd like to limit those.

Instead of a checkbox, you'd count 0 as an unchecked box. This merges the two parts of the analysis (is there an issue? if yes, then how bad is it?) into one (if there are any issues, how bad are they?)

Comment: But people tend to adjust slider settings, even if there is no damage. I would still use the checkboxes and in case of a click on it I would extend the slider.

Comment: Could you share any information you have, perhaps a source, on said behaviour? (re: sliders)

Comment: Also, @NoahKrasser, if that's an issue, smart defaults might be an idea.

Comment: I think this is a great answer but I'm very interested to see any data Noah has to back up his assertion. If that's a proven case it will potentially be quite important to some cases I am working on

Comment: Alternatively, don't have a default. Leave it blank unless clicked.